# WordPress, не подключать wp_enqueue_style в wp-admin

Tags: wordpress

Подскажите плиз, wp_enqueue_style в functions.php подключает стили в админке. Возможно ли эти стили подключать только в шаблоне самого сайта, минуя админку?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы что-то делаете неправильно. `wp_enqueue_style()` должна вызываться во время событий

- wp_enqueue_scripts - для фронтенда
- admin_enqueue_scripts - для админки

И тогда у вас будет разделение скриптов на те, что для фронтеда и админки.

Подробнее на руссском [здесь](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_enqueue_style).

Comment: я про styles, и прикол в том, что и туда и туда добавляет, Проблем с JS нет, только стили

Comment: А я вам про события. Чего вы не понимаете, так то, что события называются scripts, а по ним не только скрипты надо запускать, но и стили. Еще раз говорю - читайте документацию. И покажите свой код, сразу станет ясно, что именно вы делаете не так.

Comment: Все разобрался, спасибо, слово scripts смутило